# Trying to make a simple loop work

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that asks the user to enter a 2 digit number. In case the user enters anything but a two digit number the program is supposed to ask the user to reenter the number. I came up with a code that uses a while loop. The code however does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.   Thank you very much
This is the code I come up with :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pelindrone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        System.out.println(" Enter 2 digit number");
        num = input.nextInt();
        while(num < 10) {
            System.out.println("Enter 2 digit number");
            num = input.nextInt();
            while(num > 99) {
                System.out.println("Enter 2 digit number");
                num = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Have you tried stepping through the code? What have you done to try to debug this? What error are you getting?

Comment: Well, what does "not work" mean?

Comment: @user3695640 You can see my solution below. Your solution is longer than needed. 4 lines of code will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

**You may try this...** Just copy my entire `main method` and replace with yours.

You only need few lines of code to do the job.
Assuming you just want to validate an input to ensure it is only 2 digits. Without using an advance stuff in java, you may do it this way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;

    do 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a 2 digit number");
        num = nextInt();
    }while (num > 99 || num <10);
}
```

This is good enough for the whole thing to work. Trust me.

You don't need nested loops to do that simple task. Only use nested loops when you really have the needs. You can just combine multiple conditions in one statement and place inside the loop.

**As for why your codes didn't work well**

That is because of the condition in your outer `while-loop`. It will only run when user enters a number less than 10. But if user enters anything more than 10 (2,3,4,5,6,n digits), Your outer `while-loop` (for validation) won't run at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine if you initially give it a value that is `< 10` because then it has a chance to enter the first while loop. I've [check it in Ideone here](https://ideone.com/rVABEf) for the consecutive inputs `{-5, 0, 1, 9, 100, 1001, 50}`, and the code ends at `50` as expected.

The problem occurs if your first value is `> 10` because then it will completely skip all of the inner while loops. This means that you are only guaranteed the first value is `> 10` but not `< 100`. I've [checked this here](https://ideone.com/w3BOwc) using input of `{100, 1001, 50}` the code ends on `100` even though it should end on `50`.

To get this to work, you need to check both conditional statements at the same time `(num < 10 || num > 99)`. In addition, I would suggest removing the code duplication by using a do-while structure. The do-while checks it's conditional statement after each run. This will allow you to remove your initialization statement. The code is below ([see the Ideone here](https://ideone.com/ioFum0)).

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int num;

do{
    System.out.println("Enter 2 digit number");  
    num = input.nextInt();
} while(num < 10 || num > 99);

System.out.print("Your number is:" + num);      // guaranteed that 10 <= num <= 99
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this doesn't work is because when you enter a three digit number, it never gets to the inner while loop.

You can just simply have *one* while loop that check for *either* condition (less than 2 or more than 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Pelindrone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        System.out.println(" Enter 2 digit number");
        num = input.nextInt();
        while(num < 10 || num > 99) {
            System.out.println("Enter 2 digit number");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter more that 2 digits, which you might want to say by *does not work*, The first while condition does not catch and the program terminates. You need to catch that case in the first while too instead of the redundant inner one.

```
class Pelindrone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        System.out.println(" Enter 2 digit number");
        num = input.nextInt();
        while(num < 10 || num > 99) {
            System.out.println("Enter 2 digit number");
            num = input.nextInt();
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```